# R broom: show how many observations are included in the model

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, tidymodels, broom

I have from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

```
regressions <- mtcars %>%
  nest(data = -am) %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, data = .x)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    glanced = map(fit, glance),
    augmented = map(fit, augment)
  )

regressions %>% 
  unnest(tidied)
```

now because `mtcars` does not have missing values all models build for the different values of `am` have the same number of observations. However, if `mtcars` had missing values for the various variables, each model would had different number of observations (observations deleted due to missingness).

Is it possible to include in the final tibble the number of observations that were used in each model? Neither `tidy` nor `glance` nor `augment` provide this feature which I find really important when doing model fitting.

As Kieran suggested `glance` provides `nobs`, however how can I include `nobs` in the `tidy` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already there, isn't it? `glance` includes the number of observations as the `nobs` column.

Edit: To get just the `nobs` column from the `glanced` list column, use `hoist()` and name the new column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
mtcars_na <- mtcars
mtcars_na[1:2,1] <- NA
head(mtcars_na)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           NA   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       NA   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

regressions <- mtcars %>%
  nest(data = -am) %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, data = .x)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    glanced = map(fit, glance),
    augmented = map(fit, augment)
  )

regressions %>% 
  unnest(tidied) %>% 
  hoist(glanced, nobs = "nobs")
#> # A tibble: 8 × 11
#>      am data     fit   term  estimate std.error statistic p.value  nobs glanced 
#>   <dbl> <list>   <lis> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <list>  
#> 1     1 <tibble> <lm>  (Int…   4.28      3.46      1.24   2.47e-1    13 <tibble>
#> 2     1 <tibble> <lm>  mpg    -0.101     0.0294   -3.43   7.50e-3    13 <tibble>
#> 3     1 <tibble> <lm>  qsec    0.0398    0.151     0.264  7.98e-1    13 <tibble>
#> 4     1 <tibble> <lm>  gear   -0.0229    0.349    -0.0656 9.49e-1    13 <tibble>
#> 5     0 <tibble> <lm>  (Int…   4.92      1.40      3.52   3.09e-3    19 <tibble>
#> 6     0 <tibble> <lm>  mpg    -0.192     0.0443   -4.33   5.91e-4    19 <tibble>
#> 7     0 <tibble> <lm>  qsec    0.0919    0.0983    0.935  3.65e-1    19 <tibble>
#> 8     0 <tibble> <lm>  gear    0.147     0.368     0.398  6.96e-1    19 <tibble>
#> # … with 1 more variable: augmented <list>
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I include the nobs from glance to the tidy output?

Comment: Use `hoist()`. I've edited my answer to show how this works.